# Regex to test if string contains two forward slash or 2 hyphens

Tags: regex

I am trying to create some regex that can test whether or not a string contains 2 forward slashes or two hypens for dates.

These would pass:
10/25/1984
2005/06/24
1882-03-14
05-29-1932

Here is the regex that is failing:

```
/[\-\/{2,}/g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and check for [backreference...](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhO9Y9/1))

```
([-\/]).*?\1
```

Or simply use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/T31ryG/1))

```
-[^-]*-|\/[^\/]*\/
```

`[^`...`]` represents a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).